# How do I fix a driver error coming from writing a Dataset to redshift using scala spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, jdbc, apache-spark-sql, amazon-redshift

```
  def streamDSToRedshiftOutputIO[TIMELINE <: TimeLine : Encoder](tableName: String)(batchIntervalSeconds: Int)(dataset: Dataset[TIMELINE]): Unit = {
    dataset
      .writeStream
      .foreachBatch((batchDS: Dataset[TIMELINE], batchId: Long) => {
        FuncUtils.writeBatchDSToRedShift(tableName)(batchDS);
      })
      .option("checkpointLocation", "/tmp/ck/job_event")
      .outputMode(outputMode = "append")
      .trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime(batchIntervalSeconds * 1000))
      .start()
      .awaitTermination()
  }

  def writeBatchDSToRedShift[A: Encoder](tableName: String)(batchDS: Dataset[A]): Unit = {
    batchDS.write
      .format(source = "jdbc")
      .option("url", Env.REDSHIFT_URL)
      .option("driver", Constants.redshiftDriver)
      .option("dbtable", s"${Env.REDSHIFT_SCHEMA}.${tableName}")
      .option("user", Env.REDSHIFT_USERNAME)
      .option("password", Env.REDSHIFT_PASSWORD)
      .mode(saveMode = SaveMode.Append)
      .save()
  }
```

With the code above I get the error message during runtime:

```
java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException: 
[Amazon][JDBC](10220) Driver does not support this optional feature.
```

Full trace:

```
19/08/16 04:01:05 ERROR Client: Application diagnostics message: User class threw exception: org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQueryException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 5 in stage 2.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 5.3 in stage 2.0 (TID 22, ip-10-50-1-157.us-west-2.compute.internal, executor 2): java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException: [Amazon][JDBC](10220) Driver does not support this optional feature.
        at com.amazon.exceptions.ExceptionConverter.toSQLException(Unknown Source)
        at com.amazon.jdbc.common.SPreparedStatement.checkTypeSupported(Unknown Source)
        at com.amazon.jdbc.common.SPreparedStatement.setNull(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$.savePartition(JdbcUtils.scala:658)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$saveTable$1.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:834)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$saveTable$1.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:834)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1$$anonfun$apply$28.apply(RDD.scala:935)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1$$anonfun$apply$28.apply(RDD.scala:935)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2101)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2101)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:402)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:408)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Additionally this is the actual Case class thats contained in the dataset being written:

```
case class JobEventTimeline(
                             job_id: String,
                             job_type: Option[String],
                             in_planning: Option[Boolean],

                             team_id: String,
                             actor_id: String,
                             admin_actor_id: Option[String],
                             session_id: String,
                             client_session_id: Option[String],
                             client_created_at: Long,
                             seq_id: Long,
                             is_side_effect: Option[Boolean],

                             op_action: String,
                             step_id: Option[String],
                             job_base_step_id: Option[String],
                             field_id: Option[String],

                             server_received_at: Option[Long],

                             // "Enriched" data. Data is pulled in from other sources during stream processing
                             team_domain: Option[String] = None,
                             team_name: Option[String] = None,
                             team_is_test: Option[Boolean] = None,

                             actor_email: Option[String] = None,
                             actor_name: Option[String] = None
                           ) extends TimeLine
```

Comment: Hi, do you have any extra info in "loads" or "queries" tab of your Redshift cluster on AWS console? I want to say the exact error message. I suppose that one of fields is marked as not nullable and your dataset generates null. Also you can consider to use COPY command which has a better performance than INSERT one used in Spark's JdbcUtils.saveTable method.

Comment: Not at the moment. I assume the driver error means a query wasn't even generated. I'm going to take a look at it tomorrow once I have access to the aws account. @bartosz25

Comment: I took a look at the redshift cluster. There's nothing involving an insert statement. I don't think the query even got past the driver.

Comment: Thanks. I there is no more info, maybe you could write the data into a JSON file instead of loading it to Redshift directly and later try to split it into different parts, load them from Spark Batch to Redshift in order to find the problematic row? Or instead, take this file and load it with COPY command - in case of error, it should give you the invalid row(s) in the console.

Comment: Also, I don't know the volume of your data, but making inserts in a pure streaming way (like every 10 seconds) can be inefficient and doing a COPY works (usually) better. Search "Redshift best practices" for more info.